# understanding JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I'm reading this [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) about angular inheritance, and it started by JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance. the article said that when we do `childScope.aString = 'child string'` **the new property hides/shadows the parentScope property with the same name**, but when we do  `childScope.anArray[1] = 22` **the property values are updated on the original objects.** and I don't understand that.

 can anyone help.

 thank you in advance

Comment: I think a longer extract would be helpful. I'm almost certain I know what they are talking about but your quote is indeed misleading.

Comment: I added the link to the article, my issue is in the first explaining paragraphs s

Comment: I think that it depends on the type of the object if it was a primitive then it will be created in the children scoop (if it doesn't exist),otherwise it will look for it in the parent scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
childScope.aString = 'child string'
childScope.anArray[1] = 22
```

[image: 1]

In the first case the assignment is being made directly to the *value* of the property. JavaScript adds a new property to the child scope.

In the second case the assignment is being made to the *contents* of the property. Since the property does not exist on the child scope, JavaScript searches the the prototype chain to find the existing *contents* and modifies that.

For further reading, see [AngularJS Wiki -- Understanding Scopes and the Nuances of Prototypical Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Answer (score 3):

`a.b = c` explicitly assigns a value to the property `b` of object `a`. This will overwrite any and all implicitly inherited properties. Sample in actual Javascript with actual inheritance:

```js
function A() {}
A.prototype.b = 'c';

var a = new A();
console.log(a.b);
```

`a` does not actually have a property `b`, it's merely inherited from the prototype. Now:

```
a.b = 'd';
```

This has now attached an actual property `b` directly to `a`. The prototype still has a property `b = 'c'`, but that is not visible on `a` anymore. `a.b` is now `'d'`.

The difference between this and `a.anArray[1] = 22` is that here you're **modifying** a mutable object. You're not assigning to a property on `a`, you're getting a property from `a` and then modify it. This does not change `a`, it changes the instance of the object `anArray`. Which is visible to everything that has access to `anArray`.

Comment: thank you for responding,but I still don't understand something.you said  ` you're getting a property from a and then modify it.` , but a doesn't have a property called      `anArray`

Comment: @aName Doing a.anArray = [10,22,30] would have been a useful addition in the article to localize the difference. Doing `a.b = ...` is overwriting b. Doing `a.b[i] = ...` is not overwriting b, it's overwriting the value at index i in b.

Comment: so it depends on the type of the attribute if it's an object or a primitive

Comment: @aName No, it depends on whether you're *assigning to* the property or modify it. Yes, that somewhat depends on the type of property, since primitives aren't modifiable. But you can just as easily assign a new value to a property that used to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

Property access resolution can happen either as part of a write, or a read operation on the property. Prototypal inheritance says that only resolution as part of a read operation should involve inherited properties lookup.

Your first scenario involves a write opreation on the property - so no lookup for inherited property will occur.

In the second scenario however, the property lookup happens as part of an index lookup on the property, not a write operation on the property - ie read operation so no lookup for inherited properties